# What are the advantages of mapping a field to a type in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have about 10 million very flat (like an RDBMS row) documents stored in ES. There are say 10 fields to each document, and 5 of the fields are actually enumerations.

I have created a mapping that maps the Enum's ordinal to a Short, and pass the ordinal in when I index the document.

Does Elasticsearch actually store these values as a Short in its index? Or do they get .toString()'ed? What is actually happening "under the hood" when I map a field to a data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ES is built on top of Lucene, that is the place to look to see how fields are actually stored and used "under the hood".

As far as I understand, Lucene does in fact store data in more than just String format. So to answer one of your questions, I believe the answer is no - everything does not get .toString()'ed. In fact, if you look at the documentation for [Lucene's `document` package](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/package-summary.html), you'll see it has many numeric types (e.g. `IntField`, `LongField`, etc).

The [Elasticsearch documentation on Core Types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-core-types.html) also alludes to this fact:

> "It uses specific constructs within Lucene in order to support numeric
>   values. The number types have the same ranges as corresponding Java
>   types."

Furthermore, Lucene offers queries (which ES takes advantage of) designed specifically for searching fields with known numeric terms, such as the `NumericRangeQuery` which is discussed in [Lucene's `search` package](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#package_description). The same numeric types in Lucene allow for **efficient sorting** as well.

One other benefit is data integrity. Just like any database, if you only expect a field to contain numeric data and your application attempts to insert non-numeric data, in most cases you would want that insert to fail. This is the default behavior of ES when you try to index a document whose field values do not match the type mapping. (Though, you can disable this behavior on numeric fields using `ignore_malformed`, if you wish)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks.